# Multiple button using same xml layout file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-view

i want to create multiple button from same xml resource for this i am creating am xml layout in which i define button in a a xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/inputbox"
            style="@style/textstyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/inputbox"
            android:text="B" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and then in code i create multiple button using button which i define in xml the code is like this

```
View view = inputboxview.findViewById(R.id.inputbox);
        ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);

        //Add input boxes in control view
        for(int i=0; i<guess_world.length(); i++)
        {
            Button inputbox = new Button(context);
            //Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.inputbox); 
            //inputbox.setBackgroundDrawable(image);
            //inputbox.set
            inputbox = (Button) view;
            inputbar.addView(inputbox);
        }
```

Now the problem is that when i create a single it's just work fine but when i create more than 1 button it gives me exception that

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

So, please me in this.

Comment: you missed it, inputbar is actually a layout in which i am adding buttons

Comment: First remove all the view from parent. 

Try this: ((Button) inputbar.getParent()).removeView(inputbar);

Comment: i have tried this in other way i created xml file with button is the only view in it.

Comment: Try to access your LinearLayout and add view on your LinearLayout.

Comment: yes i am already doing it. inputbar is acutally a lyout in which i wanted to add multiple buttons

Comment: TRy this:- ((ViewGroup) inputbar.getParent()).removeView(inputbar);

Comment: @Ved not it's not working

Answer (score 0):

The error is normal, as it says, each view can only be added once.

Move your button XML into a separate file, and [inflate it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) and add it to your LinearLayout inside your for loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's not working, still the same error

Answer (score 0):

We can't guess what is your "inputbar" object so we don't know where are you adding the views.

What you can do is this, assuming that your container has the id=@+id/container and is a LinearLayout:

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

for(int i=0; i<guess_world.length(); i++)
        {
            Button inputbox = new Button(context); //or inflate from xml
            inputbox.setId(i);
            // TODO: set width and height using LayoutParameters
            container.addView(inputbox);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i have solve my problem. i have set my my drawalbe resource and style in the code. Now it's working fine